# Where to put custom RTE yaml file in typo3?

Tags: typo3

I installed the TYPO3 cms through the docker. If I want to have for example a custom RTE yaml file, like in vendor folder vendor/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/configuration/RTE/ and here are the standard yaml files, like the Default.yaml, Full.yaml, Minimal.yaml, Processing.yaml. If I want to have a Custom.yaml file, where should I put this file, since as I know the vendor folder shouldn't be touched, therefore I have to put into somewhere else. Also there is the ext_localconf.php file, I need also to register my Custom.yaml file. Woiuld be nice a little help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This documentation will give you a hint, of how you can do this.

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/main/en-us/Configuration/Examples.html

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['my_preset'] = 'EXT:my_extension/Configuration/RTE/MyPreset.yaml';
```

Answer (score 1):

This additional yaml configuration should be within your custom extension or a sitepackage extension.
The registration of the custom configuration would go like this in your ext_localconf.php file.

```
if (empty($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['customext'])) {
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['custom'] = 'EXT:customext/Configuration/RTE/Default.yaml';
}

// PageTS registering
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig('@import "EXT:customext/Configuration/TsConfig/Page/RTE.tsconfig"');
```

As the last line indicates you would need a TSconfig file as well, for making use of the preset for the custom settings/configuration you just added. So in this case RTE.tsconfig from the above mentioned path would be,

```
RTE.default.preset = custom
```

A nice doc with some examples is here.
https://blog.nitsantech.com/blog/simple-steps-to-configure-ckeditor-typo3

Happy coding!